# Can Javascript create a multi-dimensional array on the fly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am iterating over a JSON array (rec'd from a webworker AJAX call)

```
var dataReceived = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);//JSON verified as ok
                                               //dataReceived.length verified 
    var dataProcessed = []; 
   for (var i = 0; i < dataReceived.length; i++) {
    for ( var h = 0; h < dataReceived[i].length; h++) {
                dataProcessed[i][h][0]=((dataReceived[i][h][0])*30)-30;
                dataProcessed[i][h][1]=((dataReceived[i][h][1])*30)-30;
        }
    }
    postMessage(dataProcessed);
```

But i get the error

> dataProcessed[i] is undefined

Does Javascript not create multidimensional arrays on the fly?

Comment: Yes its three dimensional, no nulls

Comment: Question title changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does Javascript not create multidimensional arrays on the fly?

No, you have to create it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataReceived.length; i++) {
    dataProcessed[i] = [];        // <============= Here
    for ( var h = 0; h < dataReceived[i].length; h++) {
        dataProcessed[i][h] = []; // <============= And here
```

---

Side note: You can make that more efficient by factoring out your repeated lookups; also, you can create and initialize the innermost array simultaneously:

```
var dataReceived = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var dataProcessed = []; 
var recEntry, procEntry;
for (var i = 0; i < dataReceived.length; i++) {
    procEntry = dataProcessed[i] = [];
    recEntry = dataReceived[i];
    for ( var h = 0; h < recEntry.length; h++) {
        procEntry[h] = [
            ((recEntry[h][0])*30)-30,
            ((recEntry[h][1])*30)-30
        ];
    }
}
postMessage(dataProcessed);
```

Comment: Thanks, like your thinking about how to solve, +1 and will accept in a minute or too

Answer (score 3):

No, javascript does not create multidimensional arrays on the fly.
You will have to look for the edge case .e.g. first iteration of the loop, and
then create an empty array.

Or you can also initialize the array using || operator

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataReceived.length; i++) {

dataProcessed[i] = []; // array

for ( var h = 0; h < dataReceived[i].length; h++) {
            dataProcessed[i][h] = []; // array
            dataProcessed[i][h][0]=((dataReceived[i][h][0])*30)-30;
            dataProcessed[i][h][1]=((dataReceived[i][h][1])*30)-30;
    }
}
postMessage(dataProcessed);
```

Comment: Thanks, changed the question title to help being found too, +1